# How to detect localstorage set in parent component of React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I have a auth service that sets localstorage token after successful login

**Authentication service:**

```
async function login(email, password, remember) {
  const data = await ApiClient.post(`/api/auth`, { 
    email: email, password: password, remember: remember 
  });
  localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
  return data.token;
}

async function logout() {
  localStorage.removeItem('token');
}

export const authenticationService = {
  login,
  logout,
  get currentUserValue () { return localStorage.getItem('token') }
}
```

**App.js**

```
{ authenticationService.currentUserValue &&
<Menu>Logged In</Menu> }
<Switch>
  <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
  <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
  <Route component={Error404} />
</Switch>
```

**Login.js**

```
async function login(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const token = await authenticationService.login(email, password, remember);
      setErrorMsg('');
      history.push('/dashboard');
    } catch (err) {
      if(err.response.status === 401) {
        setErrorMsg('Unauthorized access, please login again.');
      }
    }
  }
<form className={classes.form} noValidate onSubmit={login}>
  <TextField value={email} /> 
  <TextField value={password} /> 
  <FormControlLabel
    control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
    label="Remember me"
    onChange={(e) => setRemember(e.target.value)}
    value={remember}
  />
  <Button type="submit">Sign In</Button>
</form>
```

When I login using form in `Login.js`, it doesn't render the menu `<Menu>Logged In</Menu>` from `App.js`. Is there a way to re-render when we set token value in localstorage `get currentUserValue () { return localStorage.getItem('token') }` and render menu after login?

Comment: I'd recommend reflecting the value somewhere in your store/state, where you could set it with a ```useEffect``` hook or by using a listener on the [storage event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event). It's difficult to track data stored outside of a React component in React, as it is not being watched for changes to trigger re-renders.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to store your token somewhere in a state. Then render your views based on the state of the token.

Create hooks and separate some concerns. The authentication now needs to fetch and store the token. Split those two up in these hooks: storage hook and authentication hook.

The storage hook will create a state in which you read and write the token. It also updates the `localStorage` item based on the value in the token.

Return the `token` and the `setToken` function for other components or hooks to use.

```
const useTokenStorage = () => {
  const [ token, setToken ] = useState(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    return token !== null ? token : ''
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (token === '') {
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    }
  }, [token]);

  return [ token, setToken ];
};
```

The authentication service hook will use the storage hook to set the token's value. The `login` and `logout` functions will update the value of the `token` with `setToken`, which in turn will update the `localStorage`.

Return the `token`, the `login` and `logout` functions from the hook, so the `token` can only be updated through the `login` and `logout` functions. And of course be  read through the `token` property.

```
const useAuthenticationService = () => {
  const [ token, setToken ] = useTokenStorage();

  const login = async (email, password, remember) => {
    const data = await ApiClient.post(`/api/auth`, { 
      email: email, password: password, remember: remember 
    });
    setToken(data.token);
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setToken('');
  };

  return { token, login, logout };
};
```

Use the `useAuthenticationService` hook in the component where you need to figure out what to render based on the `token`, like in your App.js

```
// App.js
const AppComponent = () => {
  const { token } = useAuthenticationService();

  return (
    { token && <Menu>Logged In</Menu> }
    <Switch>
      <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route component={Error404} />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

And use the `login` and `logout` functions where you need to update the state of the token.

```
// Login.js
const LoginComponent = () => {
  const { login, logout } = useAuthenticationService();

  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await login(email, password, remember);
      history.push('/dashboard');
    } catch (err) {
      if(err.response.status === 401) {
        setErrorMsg('Unauthorized access, please login again.');
      }
    }
  }

  render(
    <form className={classes.form} noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <TextField value={email} /> 
      <TextField value={password} /> 
      <FormControlLabel
        control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
        label="Remember me"
        onChange={(e) => setRemember(e.target.value)}
        value={remember}
       />
      <Button type="submit">Sign In</Button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

The `token` should now be in sync with the `localStorage`, even when you navigate or refresh the page.

Comment: I just tried this, it still doesn't seem to render change token after login and `history,push('/dashboard')`. It only appears when I refresh the entire page on dashboard page. I think the challenge is that `App.js` is a parent of `Login.js` and the function is being called in `Login.js` not triggering re-rendering of component on parent function on `App.js`

Comment: Ok. I got this working by passing login function from `App.js` (parent) to `Login.js` (child) so the child actually calls login function that was instantiated from parent which triggered re-render of `App.js` due to state changing at the parent level

Comment: Ahh alright! Great job. Have you also considered using the Context API?

Comment: Is context api better approach than passing function from parent?

Comment: Meh, only if you might use the token in a deeper nested child or just somewhere where can't pass it as a prop. It's not better, just a bit more flexible.